# Widget is not properly visible

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qmediaplayer

In this code which can able to play video and play `*.mp3`. code works properly,in my mainwindow.ui I added widget called `widgetGif` by drag and drop .This widget containing label also. but this widget not visible when I run the program. How can I display this widget called `widgetGif`

here is part of my code :

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QMovie>


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    player = new QMediaPlayer(this);
    vw = new QVideoWidget (this);
    player->setVideoOutput(vw);
    this->setCentralWidget(vw); //I think this is the reason

    slider = new QSlider(this);
    bar = new QProgressBar(this);
    slider->setOrientation(Qt::Horizontal);
    ui->statusBar->addPermanentWidget(slider);
    ui->statusBar->addPermanentWidget(bar);



    connect(player,&QMediaPlayer::durationChanged,slider,&QSlider::setMaximum);
    connect(player,&QMediaPlayer::positionChanged,slider,&QSlider::setValue);
    connect(slider,&QSlider::sliderMoved,player,&QMediaPlayer::setPosition);
    connect(player,&QMediaPlayer::durationChanged,bar,&QProgressBar::setMaximum);
    connect(player,&QMediaPlayer::positionChanged,bar,&QProgressBar::setValue);


    sliderVolumn = new QSlider(this);
    sliderVolumn->setOrientation(Qt::Horizontal);
    ui->statusBar->addPermanentWidget(sliderVolumn);

    connect(sliderVolumn,&QSlider::sliderMoved,player,&QMediaPlayer::setVolume);

    QMovie *movie=new QMovie(":/res/icons/giphy.gif");
    if (!movie->isValid())
    {
        // Something went wrong :(
    }
    ui->labelGif->setMovie(movie);
    movie->start();

    ui->widgetGif->setVisible(true);
}


MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_actionOpen_triggered()
{
    QString filename= QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,"Open Folder","","Open a File(*.*)");
    on_actionStop_triggered();
    player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile(filename));
    on_actionPlay_triggered();

    if(filename.endsWith(".mp3")){
        qDebug() << " file is mp3";

    }else{
        qDebug() << " not is mp3";

    }
}
```

Comment: `QMainWindow` needs a `centralWidget`. You must use layouts to include your `QVideoWidget` and also your `widgetGif` and then set it as `centralWidget` of the `QMainWindow`.

Comment: @Tarod Thank you,Can you give me sample code.please

Comment: Sure. Let me write an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QMainWindow` needs a `centralWidget`. You must use layouts to include your `QVideoWidget` and also your `widgetGif` and then set it as `centralWidget` of the `QMainWindow`.

In the following example, `textEdit` would be your `QVideoWidget` and the object `label` is like your `widgetGif`.

We have also two buttons to hide or show `label` using the method `setVisible`.

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class QLabel;
class QPushButton;
class QTextEdit;

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QWidget *centralWidget;
    QLabel *label;
    QPushButton *pushButton;
    QPushButton *pushButton_2;
    QTextEdit *textEdit;

public slots:
    void showSlot();
    void hideSlot();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QTextEdit>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    // Vertical layout
    QVBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout;

    // Widgets
    centralWidget = new QWidget(this);
    label = new QLabel();
    pushButton = new QPushButton();
    pushButton_2 = new QPushButton();
    textEdit = new QTextEdit();

    // Title and texts
    this->setWindowTitle("MainWindow");
    label->setText("TextLabel");
    pushButton->setText("Show");
    pushButton_2->setText("Hide");

    // Add widgets to layout
    mainLayout->addWidget(textEdit);
    mainLayout->addWidget(label);
    mainLayout->addWidget(pushButton);
    mainLayout->addWidget(pushButton_2);

    centralWidget->setLayout(mainLayout);

    // Set the central widget
    this->setCentralWidget(centralWidget);

    connect(pushButton, SIGNAL (clicked()), this, SLOT (showSlot()));
    connect(pushButton_2, SIGNAL (clicked()), this, SLOT (hideSlot()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::showSlot()
{
    label->setVisible(true);
}

void MainWindow::hideSlot()
{
    label->setVisible(false);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I have another simple question sir. in my code I set fixed size for mainwindow if I open .mp3. like this .   `if(filename.endsWith(".mp3")){
        this->setFixedSize(500,400);}` now I need to set again main window to resize able if I open another format.

Comment: @Learner info [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/6604/solved-unfix-a-window-previously-fixed).